# Getting the highest owner of a ToolStripDropDownItem

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm currently working on a project in which at one point, the user may right click a button which brings up a contextMenuStrip. I am already able to find the owner accurately from that strip, and manipulate the button clicked as follows:

```
Dim myItem As ToolStripMenuItem = CType(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)
Dim cms As ContextMenuStrip = CType(myItem.Owner, ContextMenuStrip)

Dim buttonPressed As DataButton = DirectCast(cms.SourceControl, DataButton)
```

But now for the tricky part. Within this contextmenuStrip, I have a DropDown menu with multiple items in there. I would assume you would be able to work your way up the ladder doing casts like above in the manner of

```
 ToolStripDrowpDownItem > ToolStripDropDownMenu > ToolStripMenuItem > ContextMenuStrip
```

Unfortunately, when I try to get the sourcecontrol from this menuStrip, it return Nothing. Any ideas on how I can get the button that was pressed from this toolStripMenuItem? My current code is as follows (in which the sourceControl is Nothing)

```
Dim myItem As ToolStripDropDownItem = CType(sender, ToolStripDropDownItem)
Dim dropDown As ToolStripDropDownMenu = CType(myItem.Owner, ToolStripDropDownMenu)
Dim menuItem As ToolStripMenuItem = CType(dropDown.OwnerItem, ToolStripMenuItem)
Dim cms As ContextMenuStrip = CType(menuItem.Owner, ContextMenuStrip)

Dim buttonPressed As DataButton = DirectCast(cms.SourceControl, DataButton)
```

Any ideas on how to go about doing what I did in that first method, but just working my way up from further down the ladder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest instead of trying to work backward to see what button was pressed and act accordingly, assign the button's behaviour when it is created.

```
Dim button As New ToolStripMenuItem("do something")
AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf DoSomething
```

…

```
Public Sub DoSomething(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as System.EventArgs)
    'do something
End Sub
```

Then you don't have to worry about it -- when it is clicked, it will do its work.

Comment: I ended up having to do a bunch of workarounds, but ultimately it was this idea that I implemented. Occam's Razor holds true once again.

Answer (score 0):

For those that come looking, it appears later versions of .NET broke the .SourceControl method during MouseUp, which had been working for years for me!

This used to work:

```
Private Sub menuSelectAll_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles menuSelectAll.MouseUp, menuUnselectAll.MouseUp
        Dim currSender As Control = CType(CType(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Owner, ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl
End sub
```

Here is my work around, which stores the parent during the opening event.  You can then reference that in the MouseUp event.

```
Private contextParent As Control

Private Sub context_Opening(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles context.Opening
        contextParent = CType(sender, ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl
End Sub
```