# SourceControl of ContextMenuStrip is Nothing in ToolStripMenuItem Click?

Tags: .net, vb.net, contextmenu, toolstrip

I have single `ContextMenuStrip` attached to more controls.

In use the `Opening` event of `ContextMenuStrip` to filter/disable some context entries.
In this case the property `ContexteMenuStrip.SourceControl` is set correctly.

The problem I have is on the Click event of a `ToolStripMenuItem`. This item is inside a `ToolStripDropDown`.

I get the parent item with code:

```
Dim tsmi As ToolStripMenuItem = DirectCast(DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Owner, ToolStripDropDown).OwnerItem, ToolStripMenuItem)
```

then I get the ContextMenuStrip:

```
Dim contextMenu As ContextMenuStrip = DirectCast(tsmi.Owner, ContextMenuStrip)
```

but now, if I check `contextMenu.SourceControl` is `Nothing`.

Do you have any idea what is wrong or why SourceControl is not set in this case?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround that is not really the answer to the question. So I will leave it open for a while.

I used the `ContextMenuStrip` `Opening` event to store locally the source object.

```
Private Sub contextGrid_Opening(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles contextGrid.Opening

  _ContextSourceGrid = DirectCast(contextGrid.SourceControl, DataGridView)

End Sub
```

and refer directly to the saved object inside all `ToolStripMenuItem` `Click` events.

Comment: Ugh, went through this whole same thing myself. It seems that this is indeed the only decent solution. In fact I tried clearing the variable on the context menu's Closed event, and found out that I couldn't even do that; it was called _before_ the `ToolStripItem`'s `Click` event. So I assume that's identical to what happens with the `SourceControl` property; an internal order-of-operations bug that clears the property before handling all events of its child objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DirectCast(DirectCast(DirectCast(
    tsmi.Owner, System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip).
    TopLevelControl, System.Windows.Forms.Control),
    System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl
```

Comment: This works only works in the `ItemClicked` event of the main toolstrip... unfortunately that event doesn't fire when clicking on sub-menu-items; they need simple `.Click` listeners. It's possible to trace back the `OwnerItem` chain to get the main toolstrip, but it seems that the `SourceControl` property is only filled in at the moment the `ItemClicked` event is triggered, meaning it's simply `null` when opening a submenu item, even if you manage to get to it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same question a couple weeks ago, and in reality, nobody could figure out why this behavior was occurring. Take a look at the [question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026380/getting-the-highest-owner-of-a-toolstripdropdownitem), the solution I was given worked great.

Comment: thank you, but I need to get the SourceControl linked to the ContextMenu when the item is clicked because this menu is reused on more DataGridView instances. I don't like to create a different ContextMenu for each DataGridView.

Comment: There's no need to have a different ContextMenu for each form object. Rather, have a single ContextMenu. As the form is loading, add a Mouse.click handler for each object, which calls a method which in turn opens up the ContextMenu. You should be able to handle it perfectly like that. If you really need the source control, which in reality was the form object clicked, have a global variable such as "ObjectToOpenContextMenu" that is set withing that right click handler. That way, depending on what the user clicks within the contextmenu, the global variable is, in effect, the sourcecontrol.